# Opening a PDO connection with global variables

Tags: php, pdo

I just have a problem on this line:

```
global $bdd; //declared in my bootstrap

$connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$bdd->resources->db->host;dbname=$bdd->resources->db->dbname",$bdd->resources->db->username, $bdd->resources->db->password);
```

I have this error :

> Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Zend_Config could not be
>   converted to string

What the variables contain is fine, i just gave a look using var_dump

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating variables as a string, break out of the string to use a variable, i.e. :

```
global $bdd; //declared in my bootstrap

$connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".$bdd->resources->db->host.";dbname=".$bdd->resources->db->dbname,$bdd->resources->db->username, $bdd->resources->db->password);
```